# php birthday validation function

Tags: php

I am trying to add a birthday validation function in my php script to make sure users are 18+. But I am stuck on how to add it in my if statement.

This is what is taken from the input fields:

```
$ydob = ($_POST['ydob']);
$mdob =($_POST['mdob']);
$ddob = ($_POST['ddob']);
$dob = $ddob."-".$mdob."-".$ydob;
```

---

The function:

```
function validateDOB($dob){

list($ydob,$mdob,$ddob) = explode("-",$dob);
$year_diff = date("Y") - $ydob;
$month_diff = date("m") - $mdob;
$day_diff = date("d") - $ddob;

if ($day_diff < 0 || $month_diff < 0) {
$year_diff--;
return $year_diff;
} }
```

---

This block is to check if all details are entered correctly. **So my question is how would I add the function here to validate if the user is over 18.**

```
if((!$username) || (!$country) || (!$dob) || (!$email) || (!$password)){

    $error_message = "You did not submit the following required information!<br /><br />";
    if(!$username){
        $error_message .= "Enter a User Name";
    } else if(!$country){
        $error_message .= "Enter a Country"; 
    } else if(!$dob){ 
                    $error_message .= "Enter a D.O.B";
            } else if(!$email){ 
                    $error_message .= "Enter a Email Address"; 
            } else if(!$password){ 
                $error_message .= "Enter a Password"; 
            }
     } else {
        ....}
```

Thank you so much.
Ray

Comment: Thank you I will look into that. My question is how to call the variables from the function or the result from the function to be used in the else if statement.

Comment: 2 notes: 1) why pass a concatenated string to validateDOB if you then explode it again? why not pass the 3 parts? 2)Users <18 can always say they're > 18  :), so your check is easily spoofable; just saying... 3) as @Rup said, checking against birthdate is way easier (but still note #2 is in effect)

Comment: Ray Hmar: or just create two numbers like yyyymmdd and subtract them, e.g. `20111110-19760331=350783`. hey, I'm 35 ;-) But that isn't exactly the question here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a much easier way to do it:

```
function validateDOB($date)
{
    $minAge=strtotime("-18 YEAR");
    $entrantAge= strtotime($date);

    if ($entrantAge < $minAge)
    {
        return false;
    }

   return true;
}
```

And then:

```
if(validateDOB($date))
{ 
   echo "Welcome";
}
else
{
   echo "Sorry, you are too young";
}
```

EDIT: To convert your date from European date format to MySQL format, you can do this:

```
$ymd = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $dmy)->format('Y-m-d');
```

You can do that before you pass it through to the function, or you could do it inside the function. Up to you.

Comment: Thanks that looks easier. The date format in the database looks like this "19-4-2003" would that work ?

Comment: This function should actually return false if $entrantAge is GREATER THAN $minAge, because you're comparing unix timestamps, not actual age. Bigger unix timestamp = younger. Just thought I'd put this here in case someone searches it out.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add in your else statement:

```
else {
   if(validateDOB($dob) <18)
   {
      $error_message .= "Not old enough<br />";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = '2010-11-05 18:55:21';
if (strtotime($date) !== false)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This `Function` returns `True` only if it is a valid date (also leap year) and also throw `FALSE` if it is not  meeting your Application's minimum age requirement.  Find Me On Best Social Network [Fun n Enjoy](http://www.funnenjoy.com/ravinder) ( http://www.myfne.com/ravinder )

```
   function checkDOB($minage="-18 YEAR")
    {
        if(checkdate( $_POST["dob_month"] , $_POST["dob_day"] , $_POST["dob_year"])==TRUE){
            return true;
        }
        $date=$_POST["dob_month"]."-".$_POST["dob_day"]."-".$_POST["dob_year"];
        $minAge=strtotime($minage);
        $entrantAge= strtotime($date);

        if ($entrantAge > $minAge)
        {
            return true;
        }

       return false;
    }
```